# Restart script from beginning after error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do the following:

1. run python script
2. if error - then restart from the beginning of the script

How can I do that?

Comment: What kind of error? (An invalid user input is rather different than, say, a segfault in some library.)

Answer (score 3):

You could put a `try`-`except`-`else` block within a `while` loop to do this

```
while True:
    try: # put your code below
        ...
        ...
    except: #Exception was raised, else will not be executed
        ...
    else: #Script succeeded without errors
        ...
        break
```